# Is it possible to set keybinding to show recent-dirs?

Tags: key-bindings

Emacs 27.1

package - **consult**

If I want to show recent dirs I do the next steps:

```
1. M-x consult-dir (C-x C-d)
2. Press "r"
3. Press SPACE
```

And only then show recent dirs!

But it's to many steps.

Is it possible to set keybind to show immediatly recents dirs

Comment: emacs manual: 17 Keyboard Macros

Answer (score 2):

```lisp
(global-set-key
 "C-c c"  ; Put the keybinding you want here, e.g., C-c c.
 (kmacro-lambda-form [?\C-x ?\C-d ?r ?\s]
                     0))
```

This is usually what `insert-kbd-macro` does.